# Has Apple hidden any tributes to Steve Jobs?

Tags: applications, macos

In Apple's software, are there any hidden tributes or memorials to Steve Jobs?

Someone told me you can find his glasses in an app but I can't find them.

Answer (score 27):

The **Reading List icon** in Safari is a tribute to the glasses.

[image: reading list]

---

Didn't know the story behind the iconic glasses - see this [Wall Street Journal article](http://blogs.wsj.com/runway/2011/11/09/and-now-you-can-own-steve-jobs-quirky-eyeglasses/) talking about it.

[image: Image from Associated Press]

Answer (score 24):

I don't know about glasses, but you have this one :

[image]

> Apple's latest version of OS X Lion contains a plethora of new
> features that are being uncovered piece by piece now that the preview
> version is in the hands of developers. One little gem recently
> discovered is a new section in the Finder called "All My Files." This
> feature helps you organize your files by criteria, such as file type,
> file creation date and last opened date.
>
> The icon for this new section is an image of a filing drawer stuffed
> with documents and dividers. Zooming in on the documents within this
> icon, one can see writing that is taken from notable quotes delivered
> by Steve Jobs and Apple.

http://www.engadget.com/2011/03/01/mac-os-x-lion-features-hidden-tribute-to-steve-jobs/

---

> This awesome image of a vinyl album found within OS X Lion’s user
> icons seems normal enough at first – but zooming in on the image
> reveals that this particular vinyl contains some very interesting
> songs…

[image]

> If you’re a fan of Steve Jobs’ keynotes, excitable personality, and
> unique marketing catchphrases, you’re sure to get some amusement out
> of this. As you can see, the tracks on the album label are names after
> Jobs’ famous catchphrases: “Magic”, “Revolution”, “Boom!”, and
> “Unbelievable.” Now that’s an album I’d love to hear! Yup, the track
> titles on the record label are all Steve-isms: “Magic”, “Revolution”,
> “Boom!” and “Unbelievable.” Now that sounds like an album I’d like to
> listen to.

http://www.mactrast.com/2011/07/os-x-lions-hidden-tribute-to-steve-jobs/

Answer (score 10):

Here's [one more](http://kashiv.com/2012/10/27/heres-for-the-crazy-ones-in-mac-os-x/): the TextEdit icon contains the text of Apple's iconic commercial [Here's to the crazy ones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TM8GiNGcXuM):

[image: TextEdit icon: Here's to the crazy ones]

Comment: The “Here's to the crazy ones” text is also hidden in many glyphs in Apple's Emoji font: 

Comment: How is this a tribute to Steve Jobs?

Comment: That precedes Steve's death.

Comment: It could be argued that the text itself was already a tribute to Steve Jobs. "Tribute (noun): an act, statement, or gift that is intended to show gratitude, respect, or admiration."

Answer (score 5):

If you ask Siri "Who is Steve Jobs?" it replies:

> Thanks for asking about Steve. Here's Apple's web page about him:
>
> [Steve Jobs Memorial](http://www.apple.com/stevejobs/)

[image: Thanks for asking about Steve. Here's Apple's web page about him: Steve Jobs]

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.businessinsider.com/steve-jobs-speech-easter-egg-2014-8:

> Simply press "Shift + Command + G" in Finder and paste in "/Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Resources/" and then open the Apple.txt file.

I was told many years ago when I was in school that the NeXT had easter eggs that would show up only if your user name was stevejobs, but I never attempted to confirm or deny that rumour.

Comment: The Apple.txt is no longer available on El Capitan (or just for me ^^)

Comment: @MrMojoRisin I can confirm, couldn't find this file either.